# Cloud function not getting triggered on database write

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing cloud functions for the first time. I've setup the cli and everything, I want my function to trigger whenever there is an operation in my users collection. Here's what my code looks like:

```
exports.testFn = functions.database.ref("/users/{userId}").onWrite(event => {
  console.log("testFn was Triggered!")
  console.log(`New write on user's collection: ${event.after.val()}.`)
})
```

I'm checking logs everytime I write/update something in my users collection there is no console statements or new logs in firebase dashboard. What's wrong? Also, How do i retrive `userId` value? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is the `onWrite` trigger for realtime database. Since you are using cloud firestore then you can use the `onCreate` to read new data added :

```
exports.dbDelete = functions.firestore.document('/doc/path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const newData = snap.data(); // data that was created 
  const authInfo = context.auth;
});
```

`authInfo` will contain Authentication information for the user that triggered the function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext